# Stretched bitmap in android

Tags: android

I'm working on a piece of code where i have to write text and images on a bitmap. Unfortunately i don't know the number of text items to be added in bitmap. To begin i create a bitmap by this

```
Bitmap bitMapBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(containerWidth,50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

the problem is .. the above bitmap is fixed size.. so after a while whatever i write does not show up on bitmap. How can i make it work, i mean a kind of stretched bitmap type. I looked in `BitmapDrawable`, but i cannot pass a drawable to a canvas like this

```
Canvas c1 = new Canvas(bitMapBuffer);
```

How can i handle this scenario?

Comment: You can pass a bitmap to a canvas.  Those two lines of code you have there have nothing wrong with them.  Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes. the above line of code works... the issue is the initial size of bitmap. Since the amount of text is unknown , having a fixed initial size would not work. The answer given below does solve the problem. But i'm just curious to know if there is better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of how big a bitmap you need. When you need to add another piece of text and this would take you over the limit of the current bitmap, you need to create a new one. Here's pseudocode for one way to do this:

```
Bitmap buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(containerWidth, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(buffer);
// ...
while (more_text_to_add()) {
    if (bitmap_too_small()) {
        Bitmap old = buffer;
        buffer = Bitmmap.createBitmap(buffer.getWidth(),
            buffer.getHeight + delta, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        c = new Canvas(buffer);
        c.drawBitmap(old, 0, 0, null);
    }
    draw_more_text();
}
```

In this code, `delta` is the added height you want to for the bitmap.

Comment: I do agree that this solution will work, but i'm little concerned with the performance issue related to creating a new bitmap every now and then. I was thinking in the lines of ... is there a way to have a stretchable bitmap .. one which stretch by itself.

Comment: You can certainly stretch a bitmap when drawing it (by changing the matrix that's applied to it in the drawing operation), but that doesn't make any more room for it.

Comment: hmmm... i implemented your solution. If it starts to kill my app.. i try for something else. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered NinePatch?